# WebRTC: Determine the chosen ICE candidate

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have a webrtc app, and let's say two clients( `client1` and `client2`), is there any way to find out what ICE candidate given by `client1` is used by `client2` and vice versa? because, every time to find this out, I have to use `wireshark` on both the clients, I thought reading the `sdp` might help, but I was wrong, as it gives all possible candidates...

**Scenario:** all `UDP` ports of client1 are blocked( blocked my me for testing purpose).
**Client1's SDP:**

```
...
a=rtcp:49407 IN IP4 <client1's IP>
a=candidate:3864409487 1 udp 2122194687 <client1's IP> 49407 typ host generation 0 // this would never work, since the udp ports are blocked...
a=candidate:3864409487 2 udp 2122194687 <client1's IP> 49407 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:2832583039 1 tcp 1518214911 <client1's IP> 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:2832583039 2 tcp 1518214911 <client1's IP> 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:973648460 1 udp 25042687 <TURN server IP> 64790 typ relay raddr <Proxy IP> rport 39963 generation 0
a=ice-ufrag:YSvrOiav8TglpCWD
...
```

Comment: Check out this thread: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/discuss-webrtc/-VReEXf9RBM/h91i7CD-oJ8J

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, taken from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137156/webrtc-determine-which-turn-server-is-used-in-peerconnection/32137157#32137157) to another question

I wrote and tested the below piece of code, works in latest versions of both firefox and chrome, `getConnectionDetails` returns a promise which resolves to connection details:

```
function getConnectionDetails(peerConnection){


  var connectionDetails = {};   // the final result object.

  if(window.chrome){  // checking if chrome

    var reqFields = [   'googLocalAddress',
                        'googLocalCandidateType',   
                        'googRemoteAddress',
                        'googRemoteCandidateType'
                    ];
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      peerConnection.getStats(function(stats){
        var filtered = stats.result().filter(function(e){return e.id.indexOf('Conn-audio')==0 && e.stat('googActiveConnection')=='true'})[0];
        if(!filtered) return reject('Something is wrong...');
        reqFields.forEach(function(e){connectionDetails[e.replace('goog', '')] = filtered.stat(e)});
        resolve(connectionDetails);
      });
    });

  }else{  // assuming it is firefox
    return peerConnection.getStats(null).then(function(stats){
        var selectedCandidatePair = stats[Object.keys(stats).filter(function(key){return stats[key].selected})[0]]
          , localICE = stats[selectedCandidatePair.localCandidateId]
          , remoteICE = stats[selectedCandidatePair.remoteCandidateId];
        connectionDetails.LocalAddress = [localICE.ipAddress, localICE.portNumber].join(':');
        connectionDetails.RemoteAddress = [remoteICE.ipAddress, remoteICE.portNumber].join(':');
        connectionDetails.LocalCandidateType = localICE.candidateType;
        connectionDetails.RemoteCandidateType = remoteICE.candidateType;
        return connectionDetails;
    });

  }
}


//usage example:
getConnectionDetails(pc).then(console.log.bind(console));
```

Comment: I got ```prflx``` for ```googRemoteCandidateType``` and ```relay``` for ```googLocalCandidateType```. Do you know what ```prflx``` means??

Comment: @anand have to check but  I think  it is the stun ice candidate

Comment: `prflx` means peer reflexive candidate. See this [link](http://www.jdrosen.net/uploads/1/5/0/0/15008848/ice-basic-tutorial.pptx)

Answer (score 5):

This question is very old, but here's what works reliably in 2021! - at least for me.

You can use the [RTCIceTransport.getSelectedCandidatePair() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceTransport/getSelectedCandidatePair) which returns an [RTCIceCandidatePair](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceCandidatePair) object (local and remote ice-candidate pairs).

Example:
To get the selected candidate pairs for sending media from a peer connection.

```
peerConnection.getSenders().map(sender => {
    const kindOfTrack = sender.track?.kind;
    if (sender.transport) {
        const iceTransport = sender.transport.iceTransport;
        const logSelectedCandidate = (e) => {
            const selectedCandidatePair = iceTransport.getSelectedCandidatePair();
            console.log(`SELECTED ${kindOfTrack || 'unknown'} SENDER CANDIDATE PAIR`, selectedCandidatePair);
        };
        iceTransport.onselectedcandidatepairchange = logSelectedCandidate;
        logSelectedCandidate();
    } else {
        // retry at some time later
    }
});
```

The above works similarly for received media on the peer connection object.
Use `RTCPeerConnection.getReceivers()` instead, in that case

Comment: This article https://testrtc.com/find-webrtc-active-connection/ also has some good info

Answer (score -1):

In chrome I used this:

```
let pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(cfg);
    
pc1.addEventListener('connectionstatechange', async (e) => {    
    if (pc1.connectionState === 'connected') {
        // Peers connected!
        let stats = await pc1.getStats();
        for (const value of stats.values()) {
            if(value.type=="local-candidate" || value.type=="remote-candidate")
                console.log(value);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Why negative vote?

Comment: Good point, I think it should be mandatory to leave an explanation for negative votes - only thing I would question is why use 'const value of stats.values()'? shouldn't that be 'var' or 'let' instead of 'const' as it's in a loop?

Comment: I use const instead of let as a protection style. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483101/for-of-loop-should-i-use-const-or-let