# How to get WebRTC selected candidate (which candidates are selected for transferring media )?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

Is it possible to get the candidates (realy/host/srflx) which are selected to transferring media data?

We need to check if the call completion connection is realy or p2p. It will be really helpful if we get the sender&receiver IP:port addresses for each type of media (audio&video).

Comment: Is using [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) an option? Or do you want the information in your app?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977679/webrtc-determine-the-chosen-ice-candidate ?