# WebRTC existing session

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

WebRTC comes essentially in 3 flavors depending on the network situation:

- No NAT - session is peer to peer
- NAT - session uses STUN but is eventually peer to peer for the media
- NAT+Firewall: in which case session is not peer to peer and media goes through a TURN server.

Is there a way/tool to figure out for an existing live session if it is using a TURN server or if it's peer to peer?

I am using chrome. If a tool exists for other browsers I am happy to know about it as well.

Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebRTC: Determine which TURN server is used in PeerConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137156/webrtc-determine-which-turn-server-is-used-in-peerconnection)

Comment: ICE is actually able to traverse many firewalls, just not the case where both peers are behind symmetric NATs.

Answer (score 1):

[this pull request](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/pull/910) for the webrtc samples makes the [constraints/getStats sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/) show the ip address. Instead of the local and remote ip [around here](https://github.com/fippo/webrtc/blob/827dc0ff9c64b8b5bf43eaf3ea22858b0ea3c38b/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/js/main.js#L271) you want the [candidateType](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtcicecandidatetype-enum) property.
If either of them is "relay" you are using a turn server. If both are "host" this is a direct connection without NAT. For all other cases NAT is used.

Note that this sample is currently a bit of a mess since the getStats API changed a bit.