# for...of loop. Should I use const or let?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, for-of-loop

When using a for of loop, both of these are allowed and work:

```
const numbers = [1,2,3];
// works
for(let number of numbers) {
    console.log(number);
}
// also works
for(const number of numbers) {
    console.log(number);
}
```

I always use `const` since I cannot fathom changing the `number` variable in any context, but when I see a `for...of` loop in other people's code, it often uses `let`. Maybe there's a drawback to `const` that I didn't see? Browser bugs?

Why use `const` and when to use `let` in `for...of` loops?

Comment: The only difference is due to the usual rules of `const` vs `let`, the fact that they're declared in a `for..of` loop declaration doesn't change anything

Comment: @CertainPerformance This question is specifically about `for...of`, I know what `const` means in general. If what you say is true, why are developpers ever using let? I see them using const everywhere else, but still let in loops.

Comment: do you assign a value to `number` later?

Comment: People probably use `let` because they're either too lazy to write additional characters, or because they don't care about the difference. Unless it actually gets reassigned somewhere, feel fee to just call it bad code and use `const` instead (IMO)

Comment: @NinaScholz As I said, I don't and can't fanthom it. But still I see `for(let x...` in examples, so I was thinking there must be something other developpers know and I don't.

Comment: There are lots of crappy examples and tutorials out there that follow bad practices, unfortunately, *especially* with a language as popular as Javascript

Comment: This [*is* a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58483101/timeline). The fact that the variables are being declared in a `for` loop declaration makes no difference at all

Comment: When you want to reassign `number` inside `for...of` for whatever reason, use `let` (Something like `anotherArray.push(++number)`. Else, use `const`.

Comment: This is not a duplicate and I can tell you EXACTLY why it is done.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing I agree with your sentiment, but the `EDIT: ` section in the text was not appropriate so I rolled it back.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica I'm glad you did, it was awkward. just we need to reopen it. However I suggest the title edit was good since it pointed to the core issue not of 'which to use' but why it's so prevalent.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica well, the question was reopened and so I moved my thoughts to their own answer.  I feel better clarifying that! The question of using it in loops really is different than general difference between them :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is a simple reason for the prevalence of `for(let i` instead of `for(const i` among even experienced devs/tutorial makers who are not modifying the value in the loop body and understand const/let.

Many people see const as a 'constant' which should never change. ever. (of course it never changes). But they further feel awkward 'redefining multiple constants with the same name'. For example, having  `const server = 'fun.example.com'` in one place, and `const server = 'boring.example.com'` in another place would be 'objectionable'.

The variables in loops (at least in most C-like syntax languages which JavaScript is based on) are the variables that change THE MOST. Nothing gets it's value changed more than the 'i' in all the for loops. The 'i' typically ends up being a 'register variable' on the CPU itself (not in RAM) so that it can 'change faster'.  And this was even true in JavaScript since it's inception with 'var', and is still true when you do a simple `for(let i=0;i<50;i++)`. ie `for(const i=0;i<50;i++)` throws an error.

So you can start to see the dissonance between an 'i' that changes (or is redefined) potentially thousands of times per second as you iterate through a list and `for(const i`.  So `for(const i...` 'looks' or 'feels' like `i` will only ever have the first value it is assigned. It seems 'wrong' to say `const i..` and on the next line of code, `i` could be totally different values each time 'through the loop'.  And even if you 'know' you are 'redefining it for each run through the loop', to some devs, that itself is questionable.

For this reason, many devs prefer to reserve `const` in JavaScript for 'values that are defined once and represent a single value throughout the 'whole execution of the program' or at least 'everything in a class'.

So the answer to the question in your 'title' (should I use) is probably 'keep using const since you have a reason and it makes sense to you'.  And the answer to the doubt you had of "why is for(let i so common"  is what I answered here as well. For some, they just have habit of `for(let` because it works for both 'for loops' and 'iterations through list'. For others, it's a conscious choice because they don't like 'redefining a const' over and over.

And I would humbly suggest that if you do use `const` please don't use `i` for the 'item' since i is so associated with an integer variable that increments. At least if you use a good name like item it feels more comfortable thinking of it as a single thing that only existed once.  And I humbly suggest that if you use 'let' also don't use `let i of` for the same reason.  Use `i` only for actual incrementing items. Ie use for(let item of items) or for(let i=0;i<y;i++)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It responds directly to the question rather than explaining the difference between `const` and `let`, which the asker clearly already understands.

Comment: This might be the reason indeed, but the reasoning makes no sense. Creating multiple variables with the same name happens all the time, when functions are called or when classes are created. Do people avoid `const` declarations in function scopes? No.

Comment: @Bergi yes they do, in most languages. using const everywhere in javascript is quite an anomaly. honestly i think people were just showing off.  it's like the people who want to put types everywhere always trying to be as restrictive as is possible in any given syntax.  you would expect let everywhere except references to fixed 'hard coded' values.  My guess people who use 'const' where let would be just as good are the same people who will vote for typscript to replace javascript.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing That does not match my experience, neither from JS/TS nor other languages. You may need to do some more functional programming to understand the mindset, but it's absolutely not about "showing off", it's about conveying intention. People use `const` because `let` would *not* be "just as good", it would be worse.

Comment: @Bergi const in something like mapping a function an an array or inline iteration  just is better in a show off sense and in no 'actual' sense.  nobody has any question about your 'intent', and nobody is going to go crazy and reuse your variable for some other purpose. and const doesn't stop them since they could just change it to let if they wanted.  const definitely has it's place, but it can also be empty virtue signaling heh.

Answer (score 61):

> Why use `const` and when to use `let` in `for...of` loops?

If there are no assignments to the identifier within the loop body, it's a matter of style whether you use `let` or `const`.

Use `const` if you want the identifier within the loop body to be read-only (so that, for instance, if someone modifies the code later to add an assignment, it's a proactive error). Use `let` if you want to be able to assign to it (because you have an assignment in your code, or you want someone to be able to add one later without changing the declaration).

You can do this with `for-of` and `for-in` loops. A `for` loop's control variable is normally not constant (since in the normal case you update it in the "update" clause of the `for`; if you don't, `for` may be the wrong loop to use), so you normally use `let` with it.

---

For clarity, here's an example with an assignment within the loop body:

```js
for (let str of ["a", " b", " c "]) {
    str = str.trim();
//  ^^^^^----- assignment to the identifier
    console.log(`[${str}]`);
}
```

If you use `const` for `str` in the above, you get an error:

```js
for (const str of ["a", " b", " c "]) {
    str = str.trim();
//  ^^^^^----- Error
    console.log(`[${str}]`);
}
```

Comment: I'd argue about "entirely a matter of style" part. `const` provides extra protection. I have seen so many times loop variable modified say for display purpose but the code below still relies on the original value.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You answered a question about performance of const, let and var before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40070682/1496143. I wonder if using const over let in a for loop would have implications for engine optimizations? I understand it's negligible in practice... just curious.

Comment: @Craig - You can't use `const` in a `for` loop in most cases (though you can in some), because of the "increment" part of the loop. On `for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i)` for instance, after an iteration and the test, when doing the `++i` part the engine creates the new `i` for the new iteration, assigns it the value the old `i` had, and then does the increment part: `++i`, which modifies the new `i`. So you can only use `const` in a `for` where the control variable doesn't change, something like `for (const x = start(); !x.done(); x.next()) { console.log(x.current()); }` *(cont'd)*

Comment: ... That's unusual enough and minor enough that I doubt it's an optimization target for engine implementers. I do use `const` with `for-in` and `for-of` loops as a matter of habit because I almost never want to modify the per-iteration variable within the block, and there I suspect (but don't *know*) there might be some benefit if you create functions within the loop body. I doubt the benefits are significant if there are any, though, as you say. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[You can use let instead of const if you reassign the variable inside the block.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
const iterable = [10, 20, 30];

for (let value of iterable) {
  value += 1;
  console.log(value);
}
// 11
// 21
// 31
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the const inside the for is not necessary. The const is used when the variable does not change inside the for:

```
let tmp = 0;
for(const num of numbers){
 tmp += num;
}
```

If you must modify the variable you can use let:

```
for(let num of numbers){
 num += 5;
}
```

But I prefer iterating over the array using this syntax:

```
numbers.forEach(num => {
  console.log(num)
});
```