# Class array for loop fails

Tags: javascript

I have this code that fails when I try to use the for loop

```js
class TestA {
  testArray = [];
  constructor() {
    this.testArray.push({
      name: "joe",
      age: 70
    });
    this.testArray.push({
      name: "mike",
      age: 50
    });
    this.testArray.push({
      name: "bob",
      age: 33
    });
  }
  testLoop() {
    for (test of this.testArray) {
      console.log(" >>> " + test.name + " " + test.age);
    }
  }
}
var a = new TestA();
a.testLoop();
```

The error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined

I can get away with that by using different kind of loop but don't understand why that doesn't work?

Comment: `for (const test of this.testArray)`

Comment: Maybe change `test of` to `let test of`?

Comment: It should be :```for (let test of ....)```

Comment: I'd point out that you don't need multiple, consecutive calls to `.push()`. Just add all the objects as arguments to a single call, and they all get added to the array. `this.testArray.push({...}, {...}, {...})`

Comment: thanks for your answers I am new to JS and had not heard of let before. Also this kind of loop only fails when used inside class function (at least in my experience)

Comment: @Coder547: I think inside a `class` definition, you're running in *strict mode*, which sets more stringent requirements. Outside `class` you can manually put your code into that mode by using the `"use strict"` declarative.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to declare `test` using `let` or `const`.

> Use const if you want the identifier within the loop body to be read-only (so that, for instance, if someone modifies the code later to add an assignment, it's a proactive error in strict mode). Use let if you want to be able to assign to it (because you have an assignment in your code, or you want someone to be able to add one later without changing the declaration).

Extracted from: [for...of loop. Should I use const or let?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483101/for-of-loop-should-i-use-const-or-let)

```js
class TestA {
  testArray = [];
  constructor() {
    this.testArray.push({
      name: "joe",
      age: 70
    });
    this.testArray.push({
      name: "mike",
      age: 50
    });
    this.testArray.push({
      name: "bob",
      age: 33
    });
  }
  testLoop() {
    for (let test of this.testArray) {
      console.log(" >>> " + test.name + " " + test.age);
    }
  }
}
var a = new TestA();
a.testLoop();
```

Comment: It would be good to clarify that he could also use the `const` keyword in this case

Answer (score 2):

You should write **let** for the line:

```
for (let test of this.testArray) {
```

Answer (score 1):

In a [for..of statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) you need to declare your loop variable (`test`) with `const`, `let`, or `var`:

```js
class TestA {
  testArray = [];
  constructor() {
    this.testArray.push({
      name: "joe",
      age: 70
    });
    this.testArray.push({
      name: "mike",
      age: 50
    });
    this.testArray.push({
      name: "bob",
      age: 33
    });
  }
  testLoop() {
    for (let test of this.testArray) {
      console.log(" >>> " + test.name + " " + test.age);
    }
  }
}
var a = new TestA();
a.testLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the function in the constructor, as the `this` is not preserved.

```js
class TestA {
  testArray = [];
  constructor() {
    this.testArray.push({
      name: "joe",
      age: 70
    });
    this.testArray.push({
      name: "mike",
      age: 50
    });
    this.testArray.push({
      name: "bob",
      age: 33
    });
    
    this.testLoop = this.testLoop.bind(this);
  }
  testLoop() {
    for (const test of this.testArray) {
      console.log(" >>> " + test.name + " " + test.age);
    }
  }
}
var a = new TestA();
a.testLoop();
```

Comment: This is completely unrelated and not necessary in the OP's case.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko But he's trying to refer to `this.testArray` right, which will be undefined

Comment: It wont. He is using this method like `a.testLoop()` so it will have `a` as a context. You could try it. The only problem was that OP hadn't declared loop variable and class body is evaluated in strict mode.

Comment: If `a.testLoop()` didn't properly set `this` to the `a` object, that would make methods almost useless. You'd need to bind it if you're going to separate the method from the object before invoking it.